# Email html multiple select box values

Tags: php, html

I am creating a basic web form. I am having trouble with the multiple select box. Here is my html code:

```
 <select multiple="multiple" name="specialties[]">
  <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="Item 3">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

I am having the form email the results on the PHP side once it's submitted. 
I know it's a little more involved than `$specialties = $_POST['specialties'];`

Since this is an array, I can't seem to get it to email the results. I know my form and email results work, it's just this variable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a consideration. You could try a service like Wufoo to make forms and put them in your page. Then you wouldn't have to worry about the email problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try imploding the Array to create a comma separated string:

```
$specialties = Trim(stripslashes(implode(",", $_POST['specialties'])));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="specialties[]">
<option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="Item 3">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

and your post

```
foreach ($_POST['specialties'] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

Does this work?